# UIPageViewController black background when sliding more

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I'm using UIPageViewController to create some introduction slides for my objective-c app.

But when I slide more in the first slide to left or slide last slider image more to right, I can see a black background.

How can I prevent user sliding more left in first slider & sliding more right in the last slider.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check scrollView content width . it should be  numberOfPages*screenWidth.First page frame x should be 0 .

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963857/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bouncing-swift

Comment: Thanks a lot .. I did not know, it was called as bounce .. I'll check it .. :)

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 code inspired by @Munahil:

```
class TutorialViewController : UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // Add view to mask default black background of UIPageViewControllers
        let bgView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)

        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy solution can be to place a `UIView` behind your `UIpageView`. This way, you won't be getting `black` background.

Also have a look at this [stack overflow's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963857/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bouncing-swift). It explains in detail how to Disable `UIPageViewController`