# Why are the view controllers shrinking horizontally when I use a swipe to navigate feature?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode7

I'm trying to use a swipe based feature in my app where I can swipe between different view controllers. I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAlg5BnYUU&lc=z12ztbcpgsq5cve2h225vpqr0valjttwg04 
and it worked fine when I used xib files as the interface for the view controllers. The only problem was that I couldn't use buttons in the xib files to go to another View Controller.

So I used storyboard Identifiers instead and this solved the problem of using a button to go to the next VC, but the view controllers just aren't sizing up to their width as they are supposed to. It's seems like some invisible constraints have just made the views shrink.

Here's my code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 3, self.view.frame.height - 66)


    let vc0 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstPage")

    self.addChildViewController(vc0!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0!.view)
    vc0!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)



    let vc1 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondPage")

    let vc1Controller = ViewController1()
    var frame1 = vc1Controller.view.frame
    frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
    vc1!.view.frame = frame1

    self.addChildViewController(vc1!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1!.view)
    vc1!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)




    let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdPage")

    let vc2Controller = ViewController2()

    var frame2 = vc2Controller.view.frame
    frame2.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * 2

    vc2!.view.frame = frame2

    self.addChildViewController(vc2!)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(vc2!.view)
    vc2!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the following recourse, its talking about the same thing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963857/disable-uipageviewcontroller-bouncing-swift

Comment: Check out `UIPageViewController`

Comment: @aaoli Hi thanks I read that page but there is a problem in the height of each of the view controllers. The second VC turns out to be longer than the first. And also, I didn't get how we check if we are on VC 2. Thanks